# Does anyone know of any problems with using WCF to expose a SOAP interface for non .NET clients?

Tags: wcf, networking, soap, network-programming, network-protocols

Does anyone know of any problems with using WCF to expose a SOAP interface for non .NET clients?  For example incompatibilities with other SOAP libraries?

This is so that the SOAP interface can be exposed for third parties to integrate with our software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the problem areas I've encountered with WCF:

- It generates WSDL that is split
  across multiple URLs. That is, one
  part of the schema is at one URL,
  another is at a different URL, etc.
  The "main" WSDL URL (the one with
  just "?WSDL" after the service name)
  references the others via `xsd:import`
  elements. Many SOAP clients (eg pre-.NET Delphi) have enormous difficulty with this idiom. So you really have to "flatten" your WSDL in order to achieve interoperability in practice. One solution is given [here](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx).
- WCF doesn't generate XML namespaces
  the same way as, say, ASMX web
  services.  WCF has a tendency to
  place any service or data contract
  into a namespace of its own
  choosing. Again, some SOAP clients have difficulty with this. You can increase you interoperability level by adding an explicit namespace to your ServiceContract and DataContract attributes.
- Many SOAP clients won't handle
  faults as nicely as WCF clients. For example,
  the proxy generation code won't
  create client-side objects for the
  faults declared in the WSDL.  The
  faults will still be transmitted to
  the client, of course, but the
  client then has to do more work to
  figure out what kind of fault it
  was.

Answer (score 1):

versions of the WS-* standards stack can also be an interoperability issue - for example the version of WS-Addressing (2003) supported by some java implementations eg Oracle BPEL is not supported by WCF which supports the later draft and 1.0 versions but not the earlier 2003 one

Answer (score 0):

Generally everything works fine. It will obviously depend on the client you're using - not everyone implement SOAP properly.

P.S. Could you please rephrase your question if you hope for more specific answer?

Comment: again, could you please be more specific?

Comment: It is a general question: I don't know what problems there could be, but I would like to see if anyone has encountered any.  Obviously I would like to know about any problems before I start coding! :)